# How to run a function after all imports have been completed in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, import, vuejs3

I am having an issue when importing a large quantitative variable in **Vue 3**. When `onMounted` runs, it appears the import has not been completed and I get the error that the variable `tesvar` is "*uninitialized*". This is the example code now, keep in mind the variable is a very large object that takes a while to load (minimizing the var is not a solution).

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { onMounted } from "vue"; //This works
import testvar from "../main"; //This is the right place to import

onMounted(() => { //onMounted runs without error
  console.log(testvar); 
  // Gives error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'testvar' before initialization"
}

</script>
```

Comment: I'm not a Vue expert, but it seems like it's not the issue with import loading for too long as imports aren't async. Looks more like a scope issue

Comment: Please share the code of `main` file

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. There's a possibility for the problem to appear if there's circular dependency, although accessing it only in onMounted shouldn't cause the error

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer thanks to help otherwhere. It had to do with my main file creating an error because of a circular dependency in the imports. I fixed this by putting `testvar` in a different typescript file.